# Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $2+2\sqrt{28n^2+1}$ is an integer, then it is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $2+2\sqrt{28n^2+1}$ is an integer, then it is a perfect square.

My work:
$2+2\sqrt{28n^2+1}=m \implies 4(28n^2+1)=m^2-4m+4 \implies m=2k$
$28n^2+1=k^2-2k+1 \implies 28n^2=k^2-2k \implies k=2q \implies 28n^2=4q^2-4q$
$7n^2=q^2-q \implies 7n^2=q(q-1)$
Now, we have $q$ and $q-1$ to be co-prime.
Here, two cases arises.
*(i)* $q=7x^2,q-1=y^2 \implies 7x^2-y^2=1$. This cannot occur because $y^2 \equiv 6 \mod7$
 is not possible.
*(ii)* $q=x^2,q-1=7y^2$.
Now, what am I supposed to do? Please help.

Comment: Problem$#7$ of http://imomath.com/index.php?options=618&lmm=0

Comment: @Hawk Looks like you've shown that $m=4x^2$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy I could not understand what you are saying?

Comment: @Hawk I believe you've shown that $m=4x^2$, i.e., m is a square. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I cannot see it, all I can see is that I have shown $m=2k$, please point out in which line I have done that?

Comment: Well, $m=2k, k=2q, q=x^2 \implies m = 4x^2$, no?

Comment: Yes, I can see it now! Thank you!

Comment: I was actually thinking of using Pell-Fermat equation, but it was not needed! Thank you,you saved an unnecessary extension and simplified the solution to make it elegant!

Comment: @Hawk you did all the work. We just helped you see where you did it.

Comment: For a *complete* proof you need to also consider the possibility that the factors $\,q,\ q-1\,$ of $\,7n^2$ could both be negative.

Comment: @BillDubuque How can $q,q-1$ be negative? Unless I am missing something very important, it is impossible.

Comment: @Hawk Please explain why they cannot be negative.

Comment: @BillDubuque Since $n$ is a positive integer, $2+2\sqrt{28n^2+1}$ is an integer, it is positive. So, $m$ is positive, therefore $k$ is positive, therefore $q$ is also positive.